# Create JSON object using PHP

Tags: php, json

### How can I achieve or create this type JSON object using PHP?

```
{ 
    "label": "Devices per year",
    "data": [
        [1999, 3.0], [2000, 3.9], [2001, 2.0], [2002, 1.2], [2003, 1.3], [2004, 2.5], [2005, 2.0], [2006, 3.1], [2007, 2.9], [2008, 0.9]
    ]
}
```

---

After several attempt I didn't find the solution.
For example I tried this:

```
$arrayDateAndMachine = array(
    "1999"=>3.0, 
    "2000"=>3.9
);   

$arr = array(
    "label" => "Devices per year", 
    "data" => $arrayDateAndMachine
);

var_dump(json_encode($arr));
```

Comment: That didn't work...? What output are you getting?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->label="Devices per year";
$obj->data = array(
    array('1999','3.0'),
    array('2000','3.9'),
    //and so on...
);

echo json_encode($obj);
```

Comment: If you get the error "stdClass not found", replace new stdClass(); with \stdClass(); (note the \ in front of the classname).

Answer (score 6):

Try using this

```
$arrayDateAndMachine = array(   array("1999","3.0"), 
                                array("2000","3.9")
                                );
```

Comment: This will put values in array as string not as number like in expected result

Answer (score 4):

square brackets `[]` in `json` is array so you have to do it like this

```
<?php

$arrayDateAndMachine = array( 
    array(1999, 3.0), 
    array(2000, 3.9),
);

$arr = array("label" => "Devices per year", 
             "data" => $arrayDateAndMachine);

var_dump(json_encode($arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the following syntax which gets the desired result and is clear to read:

```
$ar = array(
            "label" => "Devices per years",
            "data" => array(array(1999, 3.0), array(2000, 3.9) )
        );

var_dump(json_encode($ar));
```

The only difference being that in the output "3.0" is rendered as "3". If you need the trailing ".0" you could surround those values with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like this should work if you would like to declare it as JSON only and not by using json_encode. This also eliminates the need to declare multiple variables for each of the arrays inside. But this would be a viable solution only if the contents of the array for data is finite.

```
$json_string = '{ 
"label": "Devices per year",
"data": [
    [1999, 3.0], [2000, 3.9], [2001, 2.0], [2002, 1.2], [2003, 1.3], [2004, 2.5], [2005, 2.0], [2006, 3.1], [2007, 2.9], [2008, 0.9]
]}';
```