# creating a json object inside json object using php efficiently

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to make a json object inside the json object.
The json object I desire to make is:

```
{"post1" : {"id" : "1", "brand" : "brandFromQuery", "model" : "modelFromQuery"},
 "post2" : {"id" : "2", "brand" : "brandFromQuery", "model" : "modelFromQuery"},
 "post3" : {"id" : "3", "brand" : "brandFromQuery", "model" : "modelFromQuery"},
 "post4" : {"id" : "4", "brand" : "brandFromQuery", "model" : "modelFromQuery"}}"
```

What I ultimately want to do is create a json object as you see above and pass it along to the front end. And the data is the result of SQL query. Each "inner" json object is fetched from the query. Any tip on how I should create this?
Would love some efficient solutions for this. I was thinking of doing for loop in a for loop but concerned about the efficiency.

EDIT:
I'm trying to use json_encode to achieve this but i'm not sure how to implement this. what i have tried so far is 
1) [Create JSON object using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382369/create-json-object-using-php)
(creates a class and inputs the data). I really like this method because it is creating a separate class so its more modular but i just cant seem to find a way to create 4 different posts.

Comment: May god help you. Because we are human. you have to post your initial data along with your code effort man. this is not a full code provider plateform

Comment: *json_encode()* may help you. `$json_data = json_encode($prepared_array);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each inner object is a result-set from the SQL query then you just need single for-loop to create kind of JSON string.

Create main array

```
$main_array=array();
```

Now iterate over result from MySQL like this and append them in main array.

```
/* Your MySQL logic to fetch result */
$count=1;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { // assuming fetch method, you can replace it with yours.
     $main_array["post".$count]=$row;
     $count++;
}

$json_string=json_encode($main_array);
```

I think this is the best solution in which you can create the required JSON string.

Comment: op does already knows about `json_encode` solution, he is looking for more efficient solution .. from question: _I should have an array within an array and then use json_encode. But looking for bit of more efficient solution_ :)

Comment: May be he is using different method to create `array within an array` ? Let's see if this does help or not.

Comment: this was the answer i was looking for! however, in order to create the json object i intend to make, it needs 2d array using this answer. Any suggestions as to improve the performance?